# When does CPanel discard last months logs? Is the last day of the month properly processed?

Tags: cpanel, logs

I've got a website on shared hosting under CPanel 86.0.21. Under Metrics/"Raw access", there's a checkbox to enable discarding previous month's logs. How does that work, exactly?

The log processing runs every 24 hours, CPanel says that much. I'd assume it doesn't happen exactly at midnight. Does it do the discarding on the first day of the next month? If so, what happens to the log records from the last day of the previous month - are those never archived?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it do the discarding on the first day of the next month? If so, what happens to the log records from the last day of the previous month - are those never archived?

The wording can be somewhat misleading but it is referring to the previous month as if you were still in the last month. As in when March starts (end of February) all of Januaries logs would be deleted. The last day and that month would be kept until the end of the next month.